# How and where should I add the Glyphicons folder to my project?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, icons, glyphicons

It seems there is no documentation and I couldn't find any good solution/guide on Stackoverflow for this.

How and where should I add the Glyphicons folder to my project?

My app folder structure:

```
-quickstart-master
     -app (*Here are my js anf html files*)
     -node_modules
        -bootstrap
           -fonts
     ....
    -index.html
```

Comment: Sorry I thought you meant Bootstrap's [default glyphicons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons)

Comment: I don't care which icon to use. Can you post back your answer and tell me how to use this instead please? Many thanks and im sory for any confusion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bootstrap distribution files imply put it in a `fonts` folder on the same level as your js and css folders:

```
|
|--js_folder_name/bootstrap.js
|--css_folder_name/bootstrap.css
|--fonts/ <---- put all the glyphicons files here
|
```

You can edit the path in `bootstrap.css` if you want to change to a custom folder:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```